# Need to set the wallpaper of the phone from my ionic 2/3 app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on a ionic 3 app.I didnt find any plugin related to setting wallpaper,Looking for a plugin or a way to set a local or remote image as wallpaper from ionic app.

I have found one but not able to get it working (
[https://github.com/fbsanches/cordova-plugin-wallpaper](http://cordova%20wallpaper%20plugin))
.don't know the issue.

```
window.plugins.wallpaper.setImage(fileEntry.toURL(), function (error) {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error);
          } else {
            console.log('Success setting wallpaper.');
          }
        });
```

Comment: What type of device? Android, Windows, iOS? All?

Comment: This one supports android https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wallpaper

Comment: i tried it already but nothing happens.could you please share if you have a working sample

Comment: Did you look at github page: window.plugins.wallpaper.setImage('path/to/image.png', function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  else {
    console.log('Success setting wallpaper.');
  }
});

Comment: Yes i tried that methods according to documentation,the one you mentioned too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [issue #10](https://github.com/fbsanches/cordova-plugin-wallpaper/issues/10) from the project's GitHub, after import add

```
declare var window: any;
```

and in contractor, which must contain `private platform: Platform` as a parameter:

```
setWallpaper(url){
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    window.plugins.wallpaper.setImage(url);
        console.log('Success setting wallpaper.');
 });
}
```

Comment: How can we use image from our phone storage path?